# Convert mysql data to protobuf

Tags: android, ios, mysql, protocol-buffers

I have a HTTP server to respond to the rest requests from a mobile devices. Server data won't change frequently so I am thinking to store the data inside the devices. The data is read only for the users. So I am thinking to share the whole db with the devices as a file. If I update the db, I will create this file again. When user open the application, it will check for update time from the server. If there is an update, the device will download new file. I need to convert MySql db into the Android and IOS readable file. Protocol-buffers can easily read from the both platforms. Are there any way to dump MySql data into a protobuf. Or should I use a different mechanism?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if there is some kind of plugin that generates `.proto` file for your MySql data. Maybe someone will post something like that.

Comment: @serge yes, i need exactly what you said.